# How do I use the Get-AutoscaleHistory cmdlet in Azure?

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

When I try to use Get-AutoscaleHistory, I always get no results.

I've taken a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt282464.aspx but don't really have any hints.  I've imitated the example specified to no avail.

```
Get-AutoscaleHistory -Star 2015-11-11T18:35:00 -end 2015-11-15T18:40:00 -det
```

I've verified that I am using a subscription that has autoscale settings configured, and that those settings have actually caused scaling to happen, both up and down.

Has anybody used this cmdlet successfully?

Comment: Maybe try adding the ResourceId the autoscale setting is associated to (replace example ID with your resource ID).   Get-AutoscaleHistory -Star 2015-11-11T18:35:00 -end 2015-11-15T18:40:00 -res /subscriptions/b93fb07a-6f93-30be-bf3e-4f0deca15f4f/resourceGroups/Default-Web-EastUS/providers/microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/DefaultServerFarm-Default-Web-EastUS -det

Comment: Looks like that didn't work.